# How to grab "Point Forecast" values from predict(x)

Tags: r, prediction, forecasting

how can I take the forecast values from these list?

`out<-predict(x)`

I can see the column and the raw, but can not grab with `$`.

I tried `out$1` and some other different combination. But I was not successful.

These are an another information beside the blue drop-button: `Type: list[10](S3:forecast)`

Thank you for support.

Best regards.

Comment: We need a bit more information here. `predict` is a generic function that will work on many different types of statistical model, and the output object varies (including how you access its members), depending on what type of model you have. It is most commonly used on an `lm` or `glm` model, but it doesn't sound like that's what you have here. Can you show us the code (and preferably the data) that generates `x`, including the packages you are using? Otherwise, we will only be guessing at an answer.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Now I found itself. It´s possible to grab with: predict(x)$mean[1]

Comment: That's great, but no-one here has any idea what you are talking about, because we still don't know what type of model you are working with. I'm glad you got something that worked for you.

Comment: This is the complete issue: predict(ets(x), n.ahead=1)$mean[1]

Comment: But you _still_ haven't told us how you made `x`, or what kind of model it is, or what package you are using, so we _still_ don't know what you mean. None of this makes any sense to us without knowing these things. Anyway, it sounds like you have a solution, which is great.